# Installing symfony on windows with XAMPP

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, xampp, pear

I'm a LINux user and recently i moved to windows OS and there i want to start all my projects which i created on linux environment. So that i started install symfony on windows with XAMPP server..

Upgrade pear:
pear upgrade pear 
Install phing:
pear install -a http://phing.info/pear/phing-current.tgz --alldeps 
Install symfony:
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com 
pear install symfony/symfony

path variable = ;g:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony;g:\xampp\mysql\bin;g:\xampp\php;g:\xampp\php\PEAR

These are the steps i followed. and after all on commmand prompt when i type command for symfony project creation , it says "  'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." can anyone help me!!!

Comment: Dilz: There is a reason for the saying "Do your homework first". Take a look which questions you ask here one after the other. I highly suggest you to get a mate of yours and do programming together. It's much more fun as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your version of symfony ? 1.4 or 2.0 ?

With 1.4, make sure that symfony is installed in your `lib/vendor`folder and then generate your project.

Take a look at this [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/03-Symfony-Installation) for more details

Comment: im using symfony 1.4                                                  i follow that documentation and got a error like this

Comment: G:\xampp\htdocs\myproject>php lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony generate:proje
ct PROJECT_NAME
Could not open input file: lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony

Comment: Can you try this : `php lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony -V`

Comment: Got it : try `G:\xampp\htdocs\myproject>php \lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony generate:project PROJECT_NAME` with a \ before lib.

Comment: it works , its my careless mistake which the folder which was inside vendor named as symfony1.4.17 instead of symfony...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://seiler.it/installing-symfony-framework.html) is a detailed article on installing symfony on XAMPP for Windows.

Comment: i followed that article , but still i coudnt fixed the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Server-Tools/XAMPP.shtml
this is a xampp server installation link and this version is userfull to windows system and disable to linus system and this is a mysql connectivity together also.